# How to print complex data(Array of Hash) structure in perl

Tags: perl

For debugging purpose i have to print the below hash. can some one help me out in this as i am little new in complex data structure :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $issueMap;

$issueMap = {
        'project' => SOAP::Data->type(string => "abc"),
        'type' => SOAP::Data->type(string => "3"),
        'summary' => SOAP::Data->type(string => $title), #issueDesc
        'description' => SOAP::Data->type(string => $issueDesc),
        'components' => [{'id' => SOAP::Data->type(string => $component_id)}],
        'customFieldValues' => SOAP::Data->type('Array' => [
                { 'customfieldId' => SOAP::Data->type(string => 'customfield_10933'), values => [ SOAP::Data->type(string => $acbPath) ] },
                { 'customfieldId' => SOAP::Data->type(string => 'customfield_10934'), values => [ SOAP::Data->type(string => $Path) ] },
                { 'customfieldId' => SOAP::Data->type(string => 'customfield_10935'), values => [ SOAP::Data->type(string => $logPath) ] },
                { 'customfieldId' => SOAP::Data->type(string => 'customfield_10071'), values => [ SOAP::Data->type(string => "PROD") ] },
                { 'customfieldId' => SOAP::Data->type(string => 'customfield_10544'), values => [ SOAP::Data->type(string => $check_area) ] }, 
                { 'customfieldId' => SOAP::Data->type(string => 'customfield_10842'), values => [ SOAP::Data->type(string => "Unavailable") ] },
                { 'customfieldId' => SOAP::Data->type(string => 'customfield_14927'), values => [ SOAP::Data->type(string => "Unavailable") ] },
                { 'customfieldId' => SOAP::Data->type(string => 'customfield_14930'), values => [ SOAP::Data->type(string => $mcn) ] }, #MCN
                { 'customfieldId' => SOAP::Data->type(string => 'customfield_14929'), values => [ SOAP::Data->type(string => $serialno) ] }, #SERIAL
                { 'customfieldId' => SOAP::Data->type(string => 'customfield_10060'), values => [ SOAP::Data->type(string => "$user_runner") ] } #user
        ])
    }; 

    Debug
     foreach my $check (%{$issueMap})
     {
       print $issueMap ->$check."\n";
     }


Error : Can't call method "customFieldValues" on unblessed reference during printing hash.
```

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($issueMap);`

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Borodin : meh, I'm good. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started to use [`DDP`](http://search.cpan.org/~garu/Data-Printer-0.35/lib/DDP.pm) (short for [`Data::Printer`](http://search.cpan.org/~garu/Data-Printer-0.35/lib/Data/Printer.pm)) which gives a much cleaner, nice colourful and flexible output instead of tons of pages of lines that spawn across the screen two or three times.

```
use DDP;

p $issueMap;
```

have a look at [Customization of Data::Printer](http://search.cpan.org/~garu/Data-Printer-0.35/lib/Data/Printer.pm#CUSTOMIZATION) for the many options, like `expand` to make it go deeper into your structure.